# PHP object composition - access owner class' property without passing down arguments?

Tags: php, class, oop, object-composition

I have asked this question beforehand, but I might have worded it poorly. I did not get the answer.

I have an `Image` class that always creates an instance of an `Id` class when it constructs. Each Image always has an `Id`, and when `Image` is destroyed, the `Id` is destroyed as well. As far as I understand, this is called Object Composition.

My Image class (here: $myImage), during intialization/construction, creates a property: $this->id = new Id();
I want $this->id to be able to access a property of $myImage. Simple example:

```
class Image {
 public $fileSize;
 public $id;
 const validMimeTypes = array('image/png', 'image/jpeg');
 public function __construct($fileSize = 0.0) {
  $this->fileSize = $fileSize;
  $this->id = new Id();
 }
}

class Id {
 public function echoMe() {
  echo $creatorInstance->fileSize;
  echo creatorClass::validMimeTypes;
  //This is what I'd like to know how to do 
 }
}

$myImage = new Image();
$myImage->id->echoMe();
```

I would like to know how an `Id` can access one of its creator's properties.
I would like to know if there are differences between accessing class *constants* and object *properties* if it turns out to not be obvious.

For example, `Id` might need the creator object's `fileName` and `fileSize` to generate a hash, or it might need its `validMimeTypes`, which could be a const array describing that class.

I don't mind knowing if this is has better alternatives - in fact, I'm curious - but first of all I'd like to know how to achieve this without passing down arguments during the __construct() stage.

Comment: you might be able to use inheritance or traits for this also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you shouldn't use public attributes, because it breaks encapsulation.
Take a look at the code below. You can pass `$this` to the target class, and be able to access its methods and attributes:

```
class A
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->b = new B($this);
    }

    public function func()
    {
        echo "hello, world!";
    }
}

class B
{ 
    private $a;
    public function __construct(A $a)
    {
        $this->a = $a;

        echo $a->func();
    }
}

$a = new A;
```

It will display `hello, world!`

So, in your case, just use `$this->id = new Id($this);` and create a constructor to `Id` class that will set the Image instance to a class attribute.

Comment: Thank you. This seems rather obvious in hindsight, although I was hoping for a cleaner solution instead of passing down the whole object. Still, this is interesting to know. Could you explain something thought?

When you construct B, you type `A $a` into the argument. Why is that? Instead of, say, just typing $a, as you are passing the same thing anyway, no?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Object `Id` need to know the `Image` it belongs. So, you can pass the reference in the constructor like I did, or pass later using a method fot that. The result will be the same, `Id` will have a attribute that references some instance of `Image`.
The `A $a` is just to check type, there is no need to use that in your code, it's just to show that `$a` is a instance of `A`.

Comment: So, it's to make sure that what you pass down is of the correct class. It seems to give an error if I try to pass down an instance of a wrong class. Could you give an example of where this would be useful? For example, if I code B to only accept instances of A, I might as well know not to invoke B from anywhere else? I understand the concept of additional integrity, but where would this really be necessary? Thanks

Comment: Exactly. It's not necessary, but it may be easier for others to understand the code and the composition between these objects, like a self-documented code.

Comment: nice answer. +1